# Replace instead of delete and add file with ngFileUpload

Tags: ng-file-upload

[ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) deletes existing files that have been uploaded before when the user tries to upload again. This may cause duplicate file uploads if the user changes their mind about replacing the file, clicks the wrong file upload button or maybe they'd like to see what file has currently been uploaded when choosing the replacement.

I thought `ngf-keep="distinct"` might do this, but it still deletes the old file immediately.

How can new files simply replace old ones without deleting the old one on click?

Another option would be to use the `ngf-before-model-change` event and reject the change if it's null. But how can that be done?

I've tried passing on the old value and setting the model value to that old value if the model value is null. But what if the model value becomes null due to failing validation?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way, without using any directive or complex code.

```
Upload <input type="file" ng-click="clear()" >
```

Add this code in your controller -

```
$scope.clear = function () {
    angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
};
```

Comment: No that's what the code currently does, I want to prevent that.